# Validar más de un campo con Fool Proof Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-view-controller, model

Les comento que estoy teniendo un problema al validar un modelo en *ASP MVC 5*

El asunto es que necesito validar que el campo **a** sea requerido si el campo **b** o **c** no son nulos

Para eso uso [**Fool Proof Validation**](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/), el asunto es que logro que funcione solo en el caso de consultar si sólo una propiedad está vacía (**a** o **b**)

Mi modelo es el siguiente:

```
public class Conexionado{

        [DisplayName("Conexión")]
        [RequiredIfNotEmpty("Conex_BT2_Pos", ErrorMessage = "Error!")]
        [RequiredIfNotEmpty("Conex_BT2_N", ErrorMessage = "Conex_BT2 Cant be empty if Conex_BT2_N isnt!")]
        public string Conex_BT2 { get; set; }

        public string Conex_BT2_N { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Ángulo BT")]
        [Range(0, 11, ErrorMessage = "El ángulo debe estar entre 0 y 11!")]
        public int? Conex_BT2_Pos { get; set; }

}
```

En el caso anterior, necesito lograr que la propiedad `Conex_BT2` sea requerida sí y solo sí `Conex_BT2_Pos` o `Conex_BT2_N` no son nulos.

El problema es que no logro comprobar las dos condiciones.

Intenté algo como

```
[RequiredIfNotEmpty("Conex_BT2_Pos || Conex_BT2_N", ErrorMessage = "Error!")]
```

Al hacerlo compilo sin problemas, pero cuando quiero utilizar la propiedad `Conex_BT2` se dispara una excepción

> 'System.NullReferenceException' en FoolproofValidation.dll

¿Alguien tiene una idea de como solucionar esta problemática?

Muchísimas gracias por la buena onda!

**EDIT**

Estoy trabajando en un custom validation, pero estoy teniendo el problema de que debe recibir más de un parámetro, y (sin dar ningún error, sólo recibe uno)

```
public class Prueba : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string[] propiedades;

    public Prueba(string[] otherProperty): base("NOT OK")
    {
        propiedades = otherProperty;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var valor = value as string;

        foreach(var propiedad in propiedades)
        {

            var otraPropiedad = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(propiedad);
            // Get the value of the dependent property 
            var valorOtraPropiedad = otraPropiedad.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            if (valorOtraPropiedad != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(valor))
            {

                return new ValidationResult(otraPropiedad.Name + " no puede estar llena y este campo vacio.");
            }
            else
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }

        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Intento invocarlo como

```
[Prueba(new string[2] { "Conex_BT2_Pos", "Conex_BT2_N" } ,ErrorMessage =null)]
    public string Conex_BT2 { get; set; }
```

¿Alguno nota a que puede deberse?

Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Probaste con una validacion customizada?

Comment: @gbianchi estoy intentando por ese medio, lo que no le estoy encontrando la vuelta, es como manejar campos genéricos como argumentos, para recibir un array, y que sea reutilizable! Gracias por contestar

Comment: no conozco la libreria, la mire por arriba cuando la nombraste.. no es como otras que llamas a la funcion, sin parametros ni nada, y devuelve true o false?

Comment: @gbianchi exacto!, el asunto, es que no logro de ninguna manera que le lleguen N parámetros a la función del CustomValidator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El  atributo `Foolproof.RequiredIfNot` deriva del atributo `Foolproof.ModelAwareValidation`(que a su vez deriva de `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation.Validation`). El atributo `ModelAwareValidation` está marcado con `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]`. Por defecto, el parámetro `AllowMultiple` de `AttributeUsage` es  `false` **lo que significa que solo puede aplicar el atributo una vez a una propiedad**.

Tenerlo `true` y permitir que se aplique varias veces posiblemente cause problemas al establecer las funciones `$.validator.methods` y `$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters` utilizado por validación discreta.

Tendrá que utilizar algunos otros atributos de validación o crear los `ValidationAtribute` que implementa `IClientValidatable`, o confiar en la validación del lado del servidor.

**Fuente:** [Foolproof multiple validators on the same fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28512316/8933039)

> Como le comenta @gbianchi, puede implementar validaciones personalizadas en las propiedades del modelo.
>    Consulte este tutorial: [Creating Custom Validation Attribute in MVC](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301022/Creating-Custom-Validation-Attribute-in-MVC) para crear un atributo de validación personalizado para hacer el trabajo que necesite, donde debe escribir su propia secuencia de comandos de validación de `jquery` para la validación del lado del cliente en modo MVC framework si usa `IClientValidatable`, que también se explica en el mismo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la respuesta! Estoy intentando implementar un Custom Validation, pero estoy teniendo un problemita, edite la pregunta para que quede claro lo que pasa, no logro de ninguna manera recibir un Array de valores, ni una lista :S

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal no debe mesclar varias preguntas, ya que si otro usuario tiene la misma duda, el título original de su pregunta no va a corresponder con una nueva pregunta de su edición, creo que lo correcto es que realice una nueva pregunta en base a su nuevo error o problema.

Comment: Dale, lo separo entonces!, Muchísimas gracias por la buena onda!

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal, si esta respuesta ha solucionado tu problema, por favor **[acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)**. Saludos.

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal correcto, realice una nueva pregunta con las nuevas dudas y así la comunidad le podrá ayudar, si mi respuesta le ha sido de ayuda, marquela como aceptada, o espere que alguíen mas le proporcione una respuesta mejor, Saludos.